# SQliteException:no such table

Tags: android

I have created one database and earlier created two table in it. With this two tables query is executed in android application like insertion and selection query.But later when i added more tables in sqlite manager and now i wanted to insert data in one of the new tables then i'm getting the exception, SQliteException:no such table. Please tell me the solution.
Is new tables are not saved in database in?